# In the original RoboCop, why are RoboCop's POV shots at eye level of the other characters?

Tags: robocop

This always puzzled me in RoboCop. When there is a POV shot of RoboCop and he is looking directly at another character, the view appears to be at eye level. But he is way taller than everyone else in the movie, so in the POV shots, RoboCop should be looking down at the characters, not directly at them.

Comment: Because a POV shot of the top of someone's head would look crap.

Comment: @amarillo Yes, since the question seems to be about the RoboCop films in general, rather than just the first 1987 film. (Or am I wrong?)

Answer (score 6):

I think you just didn't notice when they changed the POV.

When arresting Clarence Boddicker, you can see Robocop looking down at him while he is choking him.

[image]

When confronting Dick Jones

[image]

Here you see Robocop looking at Jones at chest level, this is while Directive 4 is operating and Robocop is reeling back.

[image]

At a stated 6', Robocop isn't much taller than most of the people he interacts with. In fact, Bob Morton (Miguel Ferrer) is also 6' and in a couple of scenes you can tell that he is slightly taller than Robocop (Peter Weller is 5'10" and change).